# Primefaces IE p:tree not expanding

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jsf-2, primefaces

I am working in environment websphere v8.5, JSF 2.0, Primefaces 4.0, Internet Explorer 9.

i have also included CSS files for UI designing in my application.
My problem is:
When I run my application on IE with URL localhost it works fine when I access application on my IP say 172.20.2.106 whole page UI is change (not orignal one) and primefaces p:tree is not expanding

My Question is:
Is this issue is because of the server? or IE or anything else i don't know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved for a while. i just convert the mode of document of IE, like press F12 and

[image]

and switch to it,
but still i have a Query, What is the Compatibility of Primefaces with IE, as It also show Internet Explorer 7 standards it means some user's can run IE on 7 standard, or how to change their mode using code.